# Where can I see if bounties were posted on a question at some point in the past, if those bounties were not awarded?

Tags: support, bounty

Is there a way to see whether there have been already bounties offered for a given question? If not, what is the reason that the information (about non-successful bounties) is not (easily) publicly available (yet)?

Why I find that interesting to know: I would like to base my decision to spend points on somebody else's question on that information.

Answer (score 3):

You can check the post timeline by navigating to:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/<question_id>/timeline
```

For example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42181282/unexpected-keyword-argument-type-for-bigquery) (just an example question that I knew had had a bounty) can be accessed here:

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/42181282/timeline

Where you can see a bounty was started 2017-02-14 13:15:51Z and ended 2017-02-15 13:40:09Z.

---

For your second question about why it's not easily accessible by default, I can't say why it's not (although it has been [suggested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126447/add-a-link-to-the-timeline-of-a-post)), *but* there are userscripts which add the appropriate timeline link for you.

One such userscript is the [Stack Overflow Extras](https://stackapps.com/questions/6091/stack-overflow-extras-sox) script.

Comment: I also have [Sticky Post Headers & Question Table of Contents](https://stackapps.com/questions/7994/sticky-post-headers-question-table-of-contents) that links to post revs and timeline.

Comment: @SamuelLiew feel free to add it to the answer if you like

Answer (score 2):

You can use SEDE to query all questions that had a bounty but expired without a winner.

In the [schema](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede) the table PostNotices holds the notices that got added to a post over time. Bounties are a special type of postnotices. They are recognized by the PostNoticeType records with a classid = 2.
If a bounty is awarded to an answer the Votes table gets an extra row with votetypeid = 9. The community user can auto award a bounty if the bounty owner didn't chose and an answer matches the auto-award criteria.
If we check if a postnotice for a bounty is removed by the community user (-1) and we verify no answer for the question has a votes record with votetypeid = 9 on the date the postnotice was deleted we assume we have a case of a bounty that went to waste.

The following [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1138174) implements above functional description:

```sql
select concat(
         'site://q/'
       , p.id
       , '|'
       , title) [Question]
     , concat(
         'site://posts/'
       , p.id
       , '/timeline|'
       , title) [Timeline] 
     , pn.creationdate [Bounty start]
     , pn.deletiondate [Bounty ended]
from postnotices pn
inner join postnoticetypes pnt on pnt.id = pn.postnoticetypeid
inner join posts p on p.id = pn.postid
where classid = 2  -- bounty notice
and deletionuserid = -1  -- Community removed the bounty
and not exists (  -- no bounty was awarded 
  -- find awarded bounties for that post on that date
  select *
  from votes v 
  inner join posts bp on bp.id = v.postid
  where v.votetypeid = 9 -- bounty awarded
  and bp.parentid = p.id
  and v.creationdate = convert(date, pn.deletiondate) 
)
```

Keep in mind that SEDE is only updated once a week on Sunday.
Give a big shoutout to [Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio) for her awesome [tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial)
Hop into the [SEDE Chatroom](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede) and say "Hi!".

Comment: Follow-up question: Can anybody query the SO-DB? The data scientist within gets excited :-)

Comment: @B--rian the public SEDE instance is open for anyone, you don't even need an account. It does limit query runtime to two minutes so not all analysis will work. For that you can use the datadump. There are plenty of posts on MSE of which I answered a few: https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bsede%5D+user%3A158100+is%3Aa